# List files by date in filename Powershell

Tags: powershell, filenames, get-childitem

I hope you are well.

I am new in Powershell and am trying to make a script that allow to list files 7 days old based on the date in the filename, then copy/move them to another directory.

File Structure: 2020_06_11_DB.txt YYYY_MM_dd

I have this piece of script set up but it only match the file with the reference date (DateRef) and not the least (old) of it:

```
$SourceDB = "C:\DB\"
$DestinationDB = "C:\Destination\DB\"
$DateRef = Get-Date ((Get-Date).AddDays(-7)) -Format yyyy_MM_dd

$Query = Get-ChildItem $SourceDB -Filter "*$DateRef*" |
ForEach-object {
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $DestinationDB
}
```

I tried operators like -le and -lt but with no success. I would appreciate if you can help me.

```
Get-ChildItem $SourceDB -Filter '*.txt' | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -le "*$DateRef*"}
```

Thank you!

Comment: instead of comparing _date strings_, compare _date objects_. so convert your file name to a datetime object and compare that to your target datetime object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When comparing dates, you will want to work with `DateTime` objects. So the challenge is extracting date strings from file names and converting them to `DateTime` objects before doing the comparison.

```
$SourceDB = "C:\DB\"
$DestinationDB = "C:\Destination\DB\"
$DateRef = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7).Date

$Query = Get-ChildItem $SourceDB -File | Where {
    $_.BaseName -match '\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}' -and [datetime]::ParseExact(([regex]::Match($_.BaseName,'\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}').Value),'yyyy_MM_dd',$null) -le $DateRef } |
        Foreach-Object {
            Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $DestinationDB
        }
```

**Explanation:**

I don't want to discourage you from using `-Filter` because it is better than filtering inside of `Where-Object`. So you could filter partially that way first with something like `-Filter '*_*_*'` or wildcard your path `-Path "$SourceDB*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]*"`.

Using `-File` parameter in `Get-Childitem`, returns only files.

`(Get-Date).AddDays(-7).Date` is 7 days before today at midnight.

`$_.BaseName -match '\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}'` matches files with format `####_##_##`.

`[regex]::Match($_.BaseName,'\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}').Value` returns the matched string `####_##_##`. `[datetime]::ParseExact()` converts the matched string (format 'yyyy_MM_dd') into a `DateTime` object.

`-le` is less than or equal to operator. So `-le $DateRef` returns dates older than or equal to `$DateRef`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked well.
Thankful for the tip of using datetime objects.